# Tables containing Young diagrams

Tags: tables, subscripts, ytableau

I would like to make a table containing Young diagrams and some other text.  Also
I would like some of the diagrams to have subscripts or superscripts.  Here is my first attempt.  Does anyone know how to make it look better?

```
\documentclass[epic,11pt]{article}
 \usepackage{ytableau}
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline
$\emptyset$&$\ydiagram{ 1}$ &$\ydiagram{ 2}$ 
\\ \hline text &  &  $\ydiagram{ 2}^+  $  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\]\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Weclome. // Can you please add a screeenshot of your posted codes result to your question? Thanks. // Why do you use tabular as environment, not ytableau as given in the manual? https://mirror.clientvps.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/ytableau/ytableau.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I'd not use caged tables, see the second realization.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[aligntableaux=center]{ytableau}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\ydiagramstrut}{%
  \sbox0{\ydiagram{1}}%
  \vrule width 0pt
         height \dimexpr\ht0 + 3pt \relax
         depth  \dimexpr\dp0 + 3pt \relax
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tabular}{|>{\ydiagramstrut}c|c|l|}
\hline
$\emptyset$ & \ydiagram{1} & \ydiagram{2} \\
\hline
text &  &  $\ydiagram{2}^{+}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\]

\[
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
$\emptyset$ & \ydiagram{ 1} & \ydiagram{ 2} \\
\addlinespace
text &  &  $\ydiagram{ 2}^{\mathrlap{+}}$  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```

In the first case, I add to each row with a Young tableau a suitable strut. This is not necessary in the second case.

[image]

If, for some reasons, you don't want the tableaux always vertically centered, you can set them so locally.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\ydiagramstrut}{%
  \sbox0{\ydiagram{1}}%
  \vrule width 0pt
         height \dimexpr\ht0 + 3pt \relax
         depth  \dimexpr\dp0 + 3pt \relax
}

\begin{document}
\[
\ytableausetup{centertableaux}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\ydiagramstrut}c|c|l|}
\hline
$\emptyset$ & \ydiagram{1} & \ydiagram{2} \\
\hline
text &  &  $\ydiagram{2}^{+}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\]

\[
\ytableausetup{centertableaux}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
$\emptyset$ & \ydiagram{ 1} & \ydiagram{ 2} \\
\addlinespace
text &  &  $\ydiagram{ 2}^{\mathrlap{+}}$  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```

By the way, the `epic` option to `\documentclass` just issues a warning that the option is unused. Remove it.

Answer (score 3):

I just use the setting proposed by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz combined with `tabularray`.

```
\documentclass[epic,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[aligntableaux=center]{ytableau}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{|c|c|l|} \hline
$\emptyset$&$\ydiagram{ 1}$ &$\ydiagram{ 2}$ 
\\ \hline text &  &  $\ydiagram{ 2}^+  $  \\
  \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might get a better alignment if you use a `l`eft aligned third column instead of a center column.

It might also be worth testing the `aligntableaux=center` package option to get a nicer vertical alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[aligntableaux=center]{ytableau}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|} \hline
$\emptyset$&$\ydiagram{ 1}$ &$\ydiagram{ 2}$ 
\\ \hline text &  &  $\ydiagram{ 2}^+  $  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```